# Localizable form validation messages

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.2

How to declare localizable form validation messages in Play Framework 2.2.1, including for messages that require parameters?

For instance, given these localization messages in `conf/messages`:

```
password.tooShort="Password needs at least {0} characters."
password.doNotMatch="Passwords don't match."
```

And a form definition like this:

```
val minLength = 8
val changePasswordForm = Form (
  Password ->
    tuple(
      Password1 -> nonEmptyText.verifying("password.tooShort", p => p.length() >= minLength),
      Password2 -> nonEmptyText
    ).verifying("password.doNotMatch", passwords => passwords._1 == passwords._2)
)
```

How can the validation message for the first field (Password1) be declared in a way that the appropriate parameter will be used (minLength)?

The form definition calls `verifying`, which only accepts String messages without parameters:

```
def verifying(error: => String, constraint: (T => Boolean)): Mapping[T] = {
  verifying(Constraint { t: T =>
    if (constraint(t)) Valid else Invalid(Seq(ValidationError(error)))
  })
}
```

Also, calling Messages() during the form definition doesn't work because it leads to the default language being used, instead of the language of each request.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `play.api.i18n.Messages` during your form definition does not work because there is no `play.api.i18n.Lang` object in scope. Change your form definition from `val` to `def` and add a implicit method parameter for the Lang object.

```
val minLength = 8
def changePasswordForm(implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang) = Form (
  Password ->
    tuple(
      Password1 -> nonEmptyText.verifying(Messages("password.tooShort",minLength), p => p.length() >= minLength),
      Password2 -> nonEmptyText
    ).verifying(Messages("password.doNotMatch"), passwords => passwords._1 == passwords._2)
)
```

You need to use this form definition in a controller action with the implicit request in scope. The request will automatically provide the Lang object.

Example:

```
def myAction = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(html.myFormPage(changePasswordForm))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the build in minLength validator this will work out of the box for you. If you really want to reimplement it, checkout how the default one is implemented, the sources of Play is included so you already have them on your harddisk. You can find the build in validation logic in `YOUR_PLAY_INSTALLATION/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/validation/Validation.scala`